# What's the difference between BOSS and the Yahoo Web Search API?

Tags: yahoo-api, yahoo-boss-api, yahoo-search

If I'm building a commercial search engine to display results from Yahoo! search, should I use BOSS or the Yahoo Web Search API?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Web Search API is deprecated. Please use BOSS. The usage limits are better as is the interface.